# Get specific value from GroupBy Key in foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I've used `GroupBy()` method with 3 multiple columns for `Key` and now I'm going to take a specific value in `Key` during iteration.

```
var groupedByList = firstList.Where(x => x.Cost != 0)
                             .GroupBy(x => new { x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3 });

foreach (var item in groupedByList)
{
    var val = item.Key["item3"];
}
```

I got the following error:

`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type '<>f__AnonymousType6<string,string,string>''`

How could I get a specific value in`Key`?

Comment: What type is groupedByList?

Comment: I just edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `GroupBy` the following way

```
var groupedByList = input.GroupBy(x => new { x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3});
```

your `Key` is an anonymous type which automatically created by the compiler, containing three properties called `Item1`, `Item2` and `Item3` (in your case all of type `string`). You can access them the way you would access any other properties:

```
foreach (var item in groupedByList)
{
    var val = item.Key.Item3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Just the VS Intellisense doesn't work.